# Todo app that syncs with Google Tasks and has notification badges?

Tags: applications, notifications, to-do-list, google-tasks

Coming from an iPhone, one of the things I miss the most is the little red notification badges on my app icons. I don't understand why more Android apps don't have them (not even the phone!?). 
I digress.
Is there an app available that both syncs with Google Tasks and uses a notification badge to keep track of the number of uncompleted tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Try a different home screen manager.  Launcher Pro does this on my phone for email and texts in the app shortcuts in the launcher bar.  I don't use Google Tasks, so I can't speak to that one particularly.

Comment: Google Tasks is one component of their world that is still rather lacking, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Tick tick is the only one I can find but unfortunately their implementation makes it pretty useless (the badge only goes up to 9)

Answer (score 0):

You should try different launchers. Most of them are better than the stock ones.
So e.g.: [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher), [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher), [Launcher Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fede.launcher), and [GO Launcher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex) support adding notification badges.

The best todo app I've ever seen is [Any.DO To-do List & Task List](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anydo). Give it a try.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how this answers the question? Do the mentioned launchers bring the "notification badges", or does the "Any.do" app (links?), or is it a certain combination?

Comment: Those launchers have the option to add notification badges, that's why I listed them.
Here you can get Apex: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher

Comment: I've merged your comments into your answer. You might want to check if I got it right. Feel free to update your answer if not, or if it misses some other details.

Answer (score -1):

Try [SplenDo - To Do List](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splendapps.splendo).  It shows badge with *Today's task count* + *overdue task count* like *(2+3)*

[image]